# How to Update data with EF Core with specific table & column that stored in JSON

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

So I want to update data with EF Core, but I want to update only column that stored in my JSON. Can I do that?

For example I have database like this:

```
+============+ 
|    tblA    | 
+============+ 
|     id     | 
+------------+ 
|    code    | 
+------------+ 
|    name    | 
+------------+
|    email   |
+------------+
|   address  |
+------------+


+============+ 
|    tblB    | 
+============+ 
|     id     | 
+------------+ 
|    colA    | 
+------------+ 
|    colB    | 
+------------+
|    colC    |
+------------+
|    colD    |
+------------+
```

and my JSON will look like this:

```
{
    "Entity": [
    {
      "TableName": "tblA",
      "Fields": [
        "name",
        "email",
        "address"
      ]
    },
    {
      "TableName": "tblB",
      "Fields": [
        "colC",
        "colD"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As the JSON value, tblA will only can update `name`, `email`, and `address`. if there's any change in field `code` or other than the list. the data will not update.

So is there any solution for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can do that. Your implementation should first read the `json` and gets the columns from it and then update those column only.